# Yii2 give array fields names and save to database

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

Can I give each item that will be saved to an array and then to a database a name.

For example say I have three form fields which will be saved to the same array. 
Can I setup my fields like below or if below is not correct what is the best way to do it?

```
echo $form->field($model, 'arrayfields')->textinput([
    'name'=>'field1inarray[]',    
]);

echo $form->field($model, 'arrayfields')->textinput([
    'name'=>'field2inarray[]',    
]);

echo $form->field($model, 'arrayfields')->textinput([
    'name'=>'field3inarray[]',    
]);
```

Also how do I go about saving the array to my database in my controller/model?

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: @chinmay just it would be better to have items in array labeled rather than array[0] to get item 1 in array.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below in my view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'example[arrayfield1]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Array Field 1') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'example[arrayfield2]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Array Field 2') ?>
```

And then within my controller to save to database did the following

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new someModel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $array = $_POST['someModel']['example'];
        $model->stockists = json_encode($array); 
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Open to code improvements, need to add some validation to check whether or not a post value exists.

**Now I need to work a way for the value to be populated in my update form.**